# Ajax call return list from python flask approute

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am using ajax call to post some data and now i need to return a python list from approute back to html. how i can do this. here is my code

```
                       $('#stop').submit(function(){
 id = id
 var services = $('#service').val()
 var extra  = document.getElementById('More').value
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: "/stopservice/"+id,
     cache:false,
     async:true,
     data: {service: JSON.stringify(services),
            extra: JSON.stringify(extra),
     },
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data)

     },
     error: function(data)
     {               $.unblockUI();
         alert(data)
     }
 });
 return false
      });
       });
```

and here is my approute.
 listofdata = finallist
 return listofdata

So basically listof data is a python list..this the the return value from approute. But i am not able to get this data in ajax.,any help

Comment: You have a typo error : the last `});` must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use Flask's [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.jsonify) function (or convert the list to JSON yourself using `json.dumps` and send it back as `application/json`).

```
# In your route handler
return jsonify(list_of_data=list_of_data)
```

```
// In your JavaScript
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.list_of_data);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other approach because I have used a for loop to bind list data to html table.